# Google Contacts Address Book Schema - How to have 1 to many fields for data?

Tags: database-design, schema, database

In Google Contacts, it seems that it allows you to many as many Email Address', Telephone numbers, Address', etc as you wish.  You can simply keep clicking the add link to make as many fields as you want.

This makes me curious on how this is made in a schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a table that is named `custom_fields` (profileid,moduleid,fieldid,fieldlabel)  there you define the fields eg: phone, dob, dogs, children then in another table `custom_fields_values`(contactid,fieldid,value) you set the values for each client/custom field.

```
custom_fields
-------------
user1,contacts,1000,Dogs
user1,contacts,1001,Children
user2,contacts,1002,Car Colour

custom_fields_values
-------------
120,1000,4
120,1001,0
121,1000,0
121,1001,0
122,1002,Red
123,1002,Transparent :)
124,1002,Green
```

Comment: How do these two tables link together, by using the ids?

Then for the table contact, they store the custom field ids?

Comment: Contact table doesn't store any new ids or additional columns. These two tables link together by `fieldid`. Profileid means username, moduleid means the id of the module eg: contacts (as you can use these tables to store data for other tables too)